# Finding self and runtime jars

Tags: java, jar

In Java, how do you find the path to the jar of the currently running program, and to the rt.jar now in use by the currently running program?

(The context is a compiler targeting the JVM, which needs to look at these jars in order to resolve import statements, class references etc.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/320542/1250303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding paths..

```
String path = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```